# NaN coordinates on D3.js v4 layouts

Tags: d3.js, layout, hierarchical-data

Trying to use D3.js layouts for a treemap on JSON input of the form:

```
var data = {
  "name": "Top",
  "frequency": 0,
  "children": [
  {
    "name": "Per",
    "frequency": 1287
  },
  {
    "name": "Tu",
    "frequency": 133,
    "children": [
    {
      "name": "Mel",
      "frequency": 50
    }
    ]
  }
  ]
}
```

I got stuck at obtaining x and y positions, and I thought it is because of my lack of knowledge using .sum() or .value() to capture the frequency field. I wanted to verify my assumption so I tried the tree layout, just to see the data spatially organised:

```
var svg = d3.select(".chart").append("svg")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("width", "100%");

var root = d3.hierarchy(data);

var treeLayout = d3.tree().size([+svg.attr("width"), +svg.attr("height")]);

treeLayout(root);

var nodes = root.descendants();

svg.selectAll("circle").data(nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d, i) {
          return 4;
        })
        .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
          return d.x;
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
          return d.y;
        });
```

And the HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
  div.chart {
    height: 5000px;
  }
</style>
<div class="chart">
</div>
```

Logging the root in the console I saw that the x and y fields are still NaN. Do you see the fault in my code?

Comment: Stack snippets are for **running** code only. I edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the width and height of the SVG as percentage:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("width", "100%");
```

So, when you use a getter, you retrieve the string `100%`:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("width", "100%");

console.log(svg.attr("width"))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Of course, using the unary plus with such string gives you a `NaN`:

```js
console.log(+"100%")
```

And you're passing those `NaN`s to `d3.tree().size()`.

There are several solutions, the easiest one is just passing **numbers** to the layout size. However, as you're using `"100%"`, we can assume that you don't know the size of the SVG.

So, my solution here (again, not the only one possible) is using `d3.style` to get the attribute in **pixels**, not in percentage (but still as a string)...

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("width", "100%");

console.log(d3.style(svg.node(), "width"))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

... and then using `parseInt()` (or any other method) to get rid of that `px`:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("width", "100%");

console.log(parseInt(d3.style(svg.node(), "width")))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Finally, if you don't want to deal with strings, just use `getBoundingClientRect()`, which will return a number:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("width", "100%");

console.log(svg.node().getBoundingClientRect().width);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you are sizing your svg relative to the window size (100% the width and the height of the page). With your current code, this results in a none integer being passed to `d3.tree.size()` causing the NaN's. As Gerardo points out, this can converted from a percentage to a pixel value easily, however, using fixed value width and height isn't a terrible idea when trying to get small examples like this to work.

If you change the width and height to fixed values, then your code works. I would suggest doing this until you're more comfortable with D3 and what you're trying to achieve with this code above.

Comment: D3 can easily get the actual size. The issue is just converting the string with `px` to a number.

Comment: Yea, I saw that in your answer. I've never bothered with relative sizing and a quick google search didn't bring this up. I did notice the problem of passing `100% to the `d3.tree.size()` function causing the NaN's, hence my fixed value approach. I'll adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, it's better now.